# How to rewrite URLs in htaccess that end with recurring characters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have changed web platforms and have old URLs that I cannot and do not want to match on the new platform where the old content is now living.

I have an array of old product URLs that all have '-p-' in the URL, followed by a string of numbers and ending in `.html` (osCommerce platform URLs).

I would like to know how to rewrite:

```
/x/[rest-of-url]-p-[random numbers].html
```

to

```
/x/[rest-of-url]
```

I would like the end result to look something like this:

```
http://www.shop.com/shop/versace-black-snakeskin-pony-hair-hobo-p-2214.html
```

redirects to:

```
http://www.shop.com/shop/versace-black-snakeskin-pony-hair-hobo
```

Does anyone know if this is doable in the `htaccess` file as a rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My managed hosting service providers BeepWeb answered my question.

```
RewriteRule ^/shop/(.*)-p-(.*).html$ http://www.shop.com/product/$1/ [R=302]
```

The first argument is the URI that you are matching. The (.*) matches any characters. The second argument is the destination URL. The $1 corresponds to the first (.*). $2 would be the second (.*), and so on... The [R=302] tells the rewrite to be a 302 redirect (use [R=301] for a 301 redirect).

Using the (.*) is essentially like using a wildard. You can instead narrow this down by specifying which characters you want to match as opposed to all characters (instead of using (.*) you could use ([abc]*) which would match only against a, b and c characters).

Also, be careful that you do not match other URLs unintentionally (i.e. you need to make sure that the pattern matches are unique to the URLs being rewritten).

If you need the source reference, see the following:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Thanks again to http://www.beepweb.com for their detailed response.
Hope it helps others.